# How should we name predicates for negative conditions?

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions, predicate

I'd like to know which is considered a best practice when naming predicates in a negative condition.

I'm familiar with the convention of prepending `is` to the name of a predicate function to express that it returns a `true` or `false` value. For example, `isGreaterThanFifty(120)` clearly expresses the intent of the predicate function, that it will return true if the condition is met. Conversely, should we say `!isGreaterThanFifty(120)` when we want the negative condition, or would it be better to say `isNotGreaterThanFifty(120)`?

Should we create a predicate function that expresses:

1. the positive case (e.g. `isValid()`) and then use it with the `!` (e.g. `!isValid()`) to negate it when using it
2. the negative case (e.g `isInvalid()` or `isNotValid()`) since that is how we are using it

For example,

```
if (!isValid(data)) {
  return new Error();
}
// do something if it is valid
```

*compared with*

```
if (isNotValid(data)) {
  return new Error();
}
// do something if it is valid
```

I'm looking for code that is more readable and expresses it's intent clearly.

I'm aware that some languages like Ruby allow us to use `unless` instead of `if` conditions or even append `?` to the end of a function, but most languages do not. So my question is geared towards those languages like JavaScript that do not have such syntax.

Comment: This is pretty opinion based. I don't think there's a standard convention. Personally, I always try not to return a "negated boolean". Instead of writing an `isntValid` function, I'll write an `isValid` version, then just negate the result at the call site. I find reasoning about functions that don't negate their return to be easier. This is also encouraged by the Clojure convention of ending predicates with a `?`. I find `valid?` more readable and succinct than `not-valid?`.

Comment: i don't know about official rules, but i tend to use the second solution when it causes 2 negations all the time, like i'd replace `isFound = !condition; if(!isFound)...` by `notFound = condition; if(notFound)..`. I would never create both versions, just more optimized one or readable, depending on the code. I also tend to ignore the "is" and go for "not" as a prefix, but that's not official

Comment: Thanks for your insights @Carcigenicate and @Kaddath. I can see why it would depend on use case.

`notValid` does sound better than `isNotValid` or `isInvalid` and it also reads better in an if-statement `if(notValid(data)`.

I prefer `notValid()` to `!isValid()` since it's more readable and clearly expresses intent.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a convention around this that I am aware.

And it should be driven by your actual need, for example are you going to make this call from more than one place (where it actually would benefit the code)?  And are you possibly putting a bunch of predicates together, this could affect readability for example: `(!isValid())` looks similar to `(isValid())` which is why some prefer to use the full condition: `(isValid() == false)`.

Or better yet putting the `false` on the left which can help prevent accidentally re-assigning a value when attempting to do a condition:

ie: `false == isValid` vs `isValid == false` which can be typo-ed or accidentally be replaced by a single `=` which would be bad news bears.

Use necessity as your driver and also always consider the future you (coming back to the code) and of course, always think of your Teammates.

Comment: Interesting. Would you say `if (false === isValid(data))` to be more readable than `if (notValid(data))` as suggested by @Kaddath?

Comment: No.  I do like `notValid(data)` vs `false === isValid(data)`.   And I think in JavaScript there are less expectations than other languages like Java where DB and ORM tools like Hibernate might make assumptions on how to access the value of a boolean table column, etc.  `notValid` itself is very readable!

Comment: How about just using isInvalid(data), keeping the 'is' to hint at a boolean result yet using the antonym of the adjective.

Answer (score 0):

I find negative names such as isNotValid confusing. 
It is OK to use a negative name for a function in a negative context, but if isNotValid() is later used in a positive check, than you get !isNotValid(data). I find double negativity very confusing when reading other peoples code. So, to support future use and positive usage as well I'd go with isValid